# Set Selected Column Data in MVC 3 WebGrid to Html.HiddenFor field

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor, webgrid

I have an MVC 3 WebGrid in partial view and am having trouble grabbing data from it before my AJAX. The idea is that I click on a row, grab the first column data from that row, and then set that data in my view model. The rows also feature hovering and clicking color changes. The user then can enter more data and click submit and the entire model is sent to controller. I cannot get the selected column data to be set in the Html.HiddenFor location. Some details of note are that ConfirmationNumber should be an int. Here is my code:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ConfirmationNumber)

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var val;
        $(function () {
            $('tbody tr').live('hover', function () {
                $(this).toggleClass('clickable');
            }).live('click', function () {
                $('#ConfirmationNumber').val($(this).find('td:first').text());
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Also as an additional detail I would like to make it so that when a row is selected and highlighted that is mutually exclusive.